# Flutter - flutter_localizations incompatible with json_schema

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add `json_schema` in my `pubspec.yaml` but when I run `flutter pub get` I end up with the following errors:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.7.0.                                  

Because sockjs_client_wrapper >=1.0.14 depends on w_common ^1.20.1 and sockjs_client_wrapper >=1.0.5 <1.0.14 depends on w_common ^1.9.0, sockjs_client_wrapper >=1.0.5 requires w_common ^1.9.0.
And because w_common >=0.2.0 <1.15.0 requires SDK version >=1.12.0 <2.0.0, sockjs_client_wrapper >=1.0.5 requires w_common ^1.15.0.
Because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.16.0 and w_common >=1.15.0 depends on intl >=0.14.0 <0.16.0, flutter_localizations from sdk is incompatible with w_common >=1.15.0.
Thus, flutter_localizations from sdk is incompatible with sockjs_client_wrapper >=1.0.5.
And because json_schema >=2.0.1 depends on w_transport ^3.2.8 which depends on sockjs_client_wrapper ^1.0.5, flutter_localizations from sdk is incompatible with json_schema >=2.0.1.
So, because esiquizz depends on both json_schema ^2.2.1 and flutter_localizations any from sdk, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in esiquizz...                                
pub get failed (1; So, because esiquizz depends on both json_schema ^2.2.1 and flutter_localizations any from sdk, version solving failed.)
```

I understand that it is a problem of versions with `flutter_localisations` but I don't known how to solve it. Is there a way to use both `flutter_localisations` and `json_schema` ?

[flutter_localizations](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

[json_schema](https://pub.dev/packages/json_schema)

This is my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  json_schema: ^2.2.1 #<==================================
  flutter_localizations: #<===============================
    sdk: flutter #<=======================================
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.0+3
  cloud_functions: ^0.4.1+4
  dartz: ^0.8.7
  get_it: ^3.0.3
  flutter_bloc: ^2.0.0
  equatable: ^0.6.1
  mdi: ^0.2.2
  provider: ^3.1.0+1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+3
  sembast: ^2.1.0+1
  path_provider: ^1.4.0
  tuple: ^1.0.3
  file_picker: ^1.4.2+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can fix it with

```
dependency_overrides:
  json_schema: ^2.2.1
```